# JNI and DLL: Two way interaction (callback)

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I'm developing a dll library for java use. I am experience java programmer. I have seen tutorial on how to use JNI and how to create a DLL library, but I can't find a good resource on how to let the dll interact with the java program like a two way street.

This is a sample scenario:

In the java app, it will call a native method callNativeMethod(), then in the dll callNativeMethod(), there will be an event on which it will need to call a method on the java app which is callJavaMethod(). How can I call the callJavaMethod() from the dll.

Please suggest how can I implement it and possibly if you have a good tutorial resource for it.

//Edit: So the correct term is a callback. =P

Comment: take a look at http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html .

Comment: Take a look at [JNA](http://github.com/twall/jna), unless you're just interested in learning the ins and outs of JNI.  JNA lets you call DLL methods directly, and supports having the DLL call back to a Java method, without having to write any additional native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can get class reference by using

```
 FindClass
```

After that, you can get function id of functions of that class using

```
 GetStaticMethodID and GetMethodID
```

Then running with

```
 CallStaticVoidMethod, CallStaticIntMethod, and CallStaticObjectMethod...
```

All these needs to be with a JVM(if you already have derived header and c++ from javah.exe, you already have this so could skip JVM creation),

```
JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm) {

    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

    JavaVMOption options; 
    //Path to the java source code     
    options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=D:\\Java Src\\TestStruct"; 
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = &options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if(ret < 0)
        printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n");       
    return env;
}
```

Example(c++):

```
 jclass clas;
 clas=FindClass("projectHello/helloWorldClass");
 jmethodID meth;
 meth = env->GetStaticMethodID(clas, "sayHello", "(I)V");
 env->CallStaticVoidMethod(clas, meth,val); //val is (I) ---> parameter. Return type V ---->void
```

If you are not shure what lies behind a class, you should check for errors such as

```
 if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {return ERR_GET_STATIC_METHOD_FAILED;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to call a Java method

```
void callback(int depth) {
   ...
}
```

form C code

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_Callbacks_nativeMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint depth) {
  jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
  jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "callback", "(I)V");
  if (mid == 0)
    return;
  printf("In C, depth = %d, about to enter Java\n", depth);
  (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, mid, depth);
  printf("In C, depth = %d, back from Java\n", depth);
}
```

it's from here http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html